# Serialize long number in python

Tags: python

What would be the best way to serialize a long number in python ?

I'm thinking pickle, but it`s still returning the "shortened" version. I'd obviously to write all the digits ..

```
longNum = math.pow(2,1000)


f = open("file", "w")
pickle.dump(str(longNum), f)
f.close()

f = open("file","r")
longNum = pickle.load(f)
f.close()

print longNum
```

> 1.07150860719e+301

Comment: Unrelated, but you know you can write `2 ** 1000` instead of `math.pow(2, 1000)`, right?

Comment: math.pow returns a float. The precision is already lost before being to serialize it

Comment: sorry, yes the issue was coming from the math module losing precision , thanks !

Comment: If you really hates the `**` operator, you can just use `pow(2, 1000)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can quickly see the problem if you fire up the interpreter.

```
>>> math.pow(2,1000)
1.0715086071862673e+301

>>> 2**1000
10715086071862673209484250490600018105614048117055336074437503883703510511249361224931983788156958581275946729175531468251871452856923140435984577574698574803934567774824230985421074605062371141877954182153046474983581941267398767559165543946077062914571196477686542167660429831652624386837205668069376L
```

math.pow is returning a float, which by definition, doesn't preserve "all the digits".  By using the long integer operator `**`, your result is a long, which is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is actually an issue with print formatting, not serialization. Read [this](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html) page to see if that's what's going on.

Also, take not of gnibbler's comment on the question. I think that hit the nail on the head.